# invalid syntax for Python Telnet command

Tags: python, telnetlib

I am coding a script interpreter. It should generate a Telnet session to send AT commands.

Here is the script which it generated:

```
telentHandle = None
if telentHandle == None:
    import telnetlib
    telentHandle = telnetlib.Telnet(10.49.188.187, 23456)
    telentHandle.read_until("login: ")
    telentHandle.write(userName + "\n")
    telentHandle.read_until("Password: ")
    telentHandle.write(password + "\n")
telentHandle.write(AT + "\n")
```

When I run it, I get

```
  File "H:/code/testgen/test_script.txt.py", line 10
    telentHandle = telnetlib.Telnet(10.49.188.187, 23456)
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`10.49.188.187` isn't a valid identifier in Python (or any language). You presumably need a string: `"10.49.188.187"`.

Comment: Ha ha! So simple!. D'oh  Now I get "socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it", so connection is there & I just need to configure things properly. How on earth could I have overlooked that?